# Get calculated date from moment object react

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I have react a component that need to add some hours to a given date according to the local date.

```
render() {
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
let localDate1=(moment(processItem.beginTime).add(-offset/60,'h'));
return(
     <p>{localDate1}</p>/*need to display the 2019-09-18T16:02:00.00*/
 )
}
```

Here processItem.beginTime format is `'2019-09-18T21:49:40+08:00'`.When I console log the `'localDate1'` it.gives the following:

```
{ 
    _isAMomentObject: true, 
    _i: "2019-09-18T18:32:00+08:00", 
    _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ",
    _tzm: 480, 
    _isUTC: false, 
    _pf: {…}, 
    _locale: {…}, 
    _d: Date 2019-09-18T16:02:00.000Z, 
    _isValid: true 
}
```

The correct value is `'_d: Date 2019-09-18T16:02:00.000Z'` and I want to display it in my code. How can I extract that value from the object ?

Comment: By using format function of momentjs https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

Comment: You can simply use `localDate1.toDate()`. This is moment method which will return `Date` object from `moment` object. You can also use  `localDate1.toISOString()` this will give date in ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the value which I wanted to display by

```
let localDate1=(moment(processItem.beginTime).add(-offset/60,'h').toJSON());
return(
 <p>{localDate1}</p> /*display the 2019-09-18T16:02:00.00*/
)
```

.toJSON() solved my problem here

Answer (score 1):

According to [Moment's docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

```
const offset = moment(new Date()).utcOffset()
const str = moment(processItem.beginTime).add(offset, 'minutes')
const result = moment(str).format()//iso yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss
console.log(result)
```